# Facebook tagging multiple users using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I'm having a hard time getting the solution for this. I'm intending to tag many users using php sdk. The sdk returns **"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid keys "tags" were found in param "tags".**.

In my controller I have this:

```
$tags = array();
foreach($to as $id){
    $tag = array();
    $tag['tag_uid'] = $id;
    $tag['x'] = rand() % 100;
    $tag['y'] = rand() % 100;
    $tags[] = $tag;
}
$argsTag = array(
    'tags'=> $tags
);
$photo_details['message'] = $message;
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file_path);
$photo_details['tags'] = array($argsTag);
$upload_photo = $this->fb_obj->api("/me/photos", 'post', $photo_details);
```

Tried using $tag as well as $tags variable.

Using $tags, I got an error of **Invalid keys "0,1,2" were found in param "tags".**

Using $tag, I only tagged 1 user instead of three.

Comment: Your $tags variable with contain 3 values in item 0, because you're assigning it  `$tags[] = $tag;`

Comment: how should I be assigning it?

Comment: are you sure `$to` array containing three users?

Comment: yes. I logged it into the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
foreach($to as $key => $id){
    $tag = array();
    $tag['tag_uid'] = $id;
    $tag['x'] = rand() % 100;
    $tag['y'] = rand() % 100;
    $tags[$key] = $tag;
}
```

i dont think there be need to this part `array($argsTag);` and  this
`$argsTag = array(
    'tags'=> $tags
);`

because you defined it as array before

Comment: Nailed it! I was confused because of too much arrays for me to handle.